# Python: Cannot Create Zip File

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I simply copy-and-pasted this code from a Python tutorial website, but the code won't work.  What's missing?  I am using version 3.4.3.  Thank you.

```
import zipfile

# Create zip file
print("Creating zip archive")
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("python_zip_file.zip", mode = "w")

try:
    # Add file to our zip
    zf.write("zippy2.py")
finally:
    print("closing")
    zf.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Cindy/Documents/Python/Zip.py", line 9, in <module>
    zf.write("zippy2.py")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1326, in write
    st = os.stat(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'zippy2.py'
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Please, include the error that you are getting into the question itself. Also, in general, don't just dump all the code, don't be afraid to state the obvious: what do you expect the code to do? And what happens instead? (using words)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Add file to our zip
zf.write("zippy2.py")
```

You should have a file named zippy2.py in the folder.

Since you just copied the code, you might not have the file that was mentioned in the code. create file 
zippy2.py in the same folder and check.

Answer (score 0):

Try learning with this..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import zipfile 

print("Creating zip archive")
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(‘Archive.zip’, ‘w’) #Archive is the name of the zip file
zip.write(‘file.txt’)  #file.txt should be in the current working directory
zip.write(‘file1.txt’) #file1.txt too
zip.close()
```